# Autocorrelation of given signal.

Tags: signal-processing, correlation

I don't understand how the autocorrelation of a given input signal is determined.
I've got the answers, but don't understand how they were derived.

Given is the following input signal $u(t)$

$u(t) = 1$ $\qquad$ if $\quad$ $t=1$ and $2$

$u(t) = -1$ $\quad$if $\quad$ $t=3$ and $4$

and $u(t+4)=u(t)$

I understand that the autocorrelation function is equal to:

$R_u(\tau)=\bar{E}u(t)u(t-\tau)=lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N}\Sigma^N_{t=1}Eu(t)u(t-\tau)$

The answers state that for $\tau = 0, 1, 2$ we get:

$R_u(0)=lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N}\Sigma^N_{t=1}u^2(t)=1$

$R_u(1)=lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N}\Sigma^N_{t=1}u(t)u(t-1)=0$

$R_u(2)=lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N}\Sigma^N_{t=1}u(t)u(t-2)=-1$

I don't understand how the $0 , 1$ and $-1$ result from the limits to $\infty$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a signal is periodic so is its autocorrelation, and with the same period.

Given
$$
\eqalign{
  & u(t + T) = u(t)  \cr 
  & R(\tau ) = E\left( {u(t)u(t + \tau )} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N\, \to \,\infty } {1 \over N}\sum\limits_{t = 1}^N {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  \cr} 
$$
we have in fact
$$
R(\tau  + T) = E\left( {u(t)u(t + \tau  + T)} \right) = E\left( {u(t)u(t + \tau  + T)} \right) = E\left( {u(t)u(t + \tau )} \right)
$$

Then if $R(\tau)$ is periodic, we can limit the sum to only the period, because
$$
\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N\, \to \,\infty } {1 \over N}\sum\limits_{t = 1}^N {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N\, \to \,\infty } {1 \over {nT + q}}\left( {\sum\limits_{t = 1}^T {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  + \sum\limits_{t = T + 1}^{2T} {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  +  \cdots  + \sum\limits_{t = (n - 1)T + 1}^{nT} {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  + \sum\limits_{t = nT + 1}^{nT + q} {u(t)u(t + \tau )} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N\, \to \,\infty } {1 \over {nT + q}}\left( {n\sum\limits_{t = 1}^T {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  + \sum\limits_{t = 1}^q {u(t)u(t + \tau )} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N\, \to \,\infty } {n \over {nT + q}}\sum\limits_{t = 1}^T {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N\, \to \,\infty } {1 \over {nT + q}}\sum\limits_{t = 1}^q {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over T}\sum\limits_{t = 1}^T {u(t)u(t + \tau )}  \cr} 
$$

That fixed I think you can clear your doubts.

And, by the way, if you take  $t$ and $\tau$ to start from $0$, you will have an easier task.